# Where can I find the source code of C++'s generic.h?

Tags: generics, robotics, lego-mindstorms

At present, I'm using a C-like language (NXC) to control a LEGO MINDSTORMS robot. That C-like language doesn't have support for generics (or, not being C++, classes. But I digress). However, I read in an outdated C++ book that either C or C++ has a file called generic.h, which contains helpful preprocessor macros (ie name2 and declare) for doing this.

Is there any way I can get a copy of this file?

Comment: Have you tried googling for this name, say  +"generic.h" +source ?

Comment: Yes, I have. Most of the things came up with other "generic.h" files. Oddly enougth, googling that brings up this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may lead you to a couple of files: http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&q=generic.h+name2+declare

Comment: Unfortunately, google codesearch is not working anymore.